# Both background image as background color not visible in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, background, background-image, background-color, invisible

I am testing a site on localhost with Firefox and now I am seeing that the background image and color I gave isn't showing at all in Chrome. In IE it is showing in IE9 but not in IE8 or 7... So In Chrome, IE7 and IE8 I am neither seeing an image as a color...

What might be the problem? I am using both a color as a image. This is the code I am using:

```
background: url("http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/bg.png") no-repeat scroll left 550px center #222;
```

PS I am using a left 550px because I don't want to use right -80px... Using a minus isn't good I am told...

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the color before the url

according to W3C: 
background: [background-color] [background-image] [background-repeat] [background-attachment] [background-position];

So your code should look like this (I removed the double left property, if it's a positive number than it's automatically pushing 550px from the left):

```
background: #222 url("http://localhost/test/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/bg.png") no-repeat scroll 550px center;
```

Comment: The 550px is for positioning the background. Thanks for your answer, but I already tried that and had no luck.

Comment: Hey Johan, did you try removing the 'left' and just keep 550px?